# OpenGL - Generate Normal of rendered scene

Tags: c#, opengl, graphics, normals

I am drawing a scene by drawing vertices one by one. I use opentk and C#, the draw code looks like this:

```
GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.VertexArray);
GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.NormalArray);
GL.VertexPointer(3, VertexPointerType.Float, 0, parameterArray);
GL.Color3(color.R / 255.0, color.G / 255.0, color.B / 255.0);
GL.NormalPointer(NormalPointerType.Float, 0, normalArray);
GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Triangles, 0, parameterArray!.Length / 3);    
GL.DisableClientState(ArrayCap.NormalArray);
GL.DisableClientState(ArrayCap.VertexArray);
```

But since OpenTK is just another wrapper aroung OpenGL, i don't think the code details matter much.

I do that for all my vertices and then grab the image from the backbuffer with ReadPixels.

**This is not for display - I am then running further simulations on the generated pictures.**

Now, to expand my simulations, i kind of need the normal vector for each pixel.

What i actually need in the end is the angle between the surface and the camera direction for each pixel of the model.

In my understanding, OpenGL internally will generate normal vectors when lighting (although i currently render without lighting at all), so can i somehow let it  generate these?

I have the vague idea of rendering the scene in a 3x higher resolution, then use the Z values to generate normals from each 4x4 block, but that would involve a lot of CPU-heavy vector operations. Can't i use opengl to give me the normal vectors?
I have the normals of the vertices of course, but i can't know which vertex is shown in a pixel (at least not without iterating over all vertices for each pixel).

Any tip on how i bring openGL to do it for me?

Aren't normal maps from hi-res models also generated like this (Although they are at some step transformed to tangent space if my understanding is correct, and i need them in object space or ultimately in view space.

Comment: OpenGL doesn't calculate normals for you. What it can do is interpolate normals given at the vertices over the triangle. Usually, I would advise to use a framebuffer object and just have multiple outputs, but the GL version you are using so ancient that framebuffers might not be supported.

Comment: I don't quite understand you. Can you give me some hint about what you mean with the framebuffer approach? I can generate and bind a framebuffer and render the scene to it, what do you mean with "multiple outputs" and how would i get normals from that? I mean, my vertices have normals already (each of my vertices consists of 4 vectors, one is the normal vector for that vertex), but i need a way to transform that to the rendered pixels.

Comment: [Framebuffer Objects](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer_Object) allow you to have more than one Color Attachment (it basically allows you to write outputs to multiple different buffers). But afaik, that only works with modern GL (with shaders). Transformation of the normals should work like in any tutorial about lighting/illumination: You multiply the normals with the rotational part of the model matrix. Not sure how that works without shaders.

Comment: Why do you think it's ancient? I think i can have shaders. I also more or less get the theoretical background of the needed calculations, i am just not sure how i get opengl to do it for me. If i understand you correct, you would propose binding a second Color attachment to get a second "target" for rendering into, and then use a shader to render the normal values instead of model color?

Comment: Yeah, that is exactly what I meant. I said ancient OpenGL because you are using the fixed function pipeline. Commands like `VertexPointer`, `Color3` are deprecated since OpenGL 3.3 which was released in 2010.

Comment: Well, i am no expert for openGL, and just needed a way to render vertices that i already had in an array. I try to learn about the other ways there are if you say it's deprecated. I Also already noticed that performance is bad, and i would love to have a way that stores the vertices in VRAM between the pictures, as the model is always the same (just rotated/translated).
Some of the problem comes from the decision to use C# (helps with other parts of the project), and the OpenTK bindings i use might be a bit older.

Comment: Do you happen to have an example of doing something similar with a shader, or some link to read for more information?